# prepareForSegue collectionView indexPath using swift

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue, collectionview

I don't find any good example to do what I want using swift so I allow myself to ask the question.

Im using a collectionView to display PFObjects and I want to send the displayed cell data to a second controller using prepareForSegue.

At this point, Im struggling to make this part of the code works:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "goto_answerquestion"){
            var indexpath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
        }
    }
```

this line:

```
var indexpath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
```

triggers the following error:

```
(UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: Int)-> Int does not have a member named 'indexPathsForSelectedItems'
```

please let me know if Im using the wrong method, or if you need additional data to have the appropriate overview of the problem.

**ANSWER**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "segue_identifier"){
            // check for / catch all visible cell(s)
            for item in self.collectionView!.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell] {
                var indexpath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(item as CollectionViewCell)!
                var cell : CollectionViewCell = self.collectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexpath) as CollectionViewCell

                // Grab related PFObject
                var objectData:PFObject = self.questionData.objectAtIndex(indexpath.row) as PFObject

                // Pass PFObject to second ViewController
                let theDestination = (segue.destinationViewController as answerPageViewController)
                theDestination.questionObject = objectData
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `indexPathsForSelectedItems` returns an array, but you assign it to a variable of type `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just are trying to just find the index path of the cell tapped, and not have multiple, you could do this in your prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender as UICollectionViewCell)
    // do what you need now with the indexPath
}
```

`sender` in this situation is the cell you tapped, so you just need to cast it to UICollectionViewCell (or a custom cell subclass, if you made one).

**UPDATE**:
Swift 1.2 introduced `as!` to replace `as` for this purpose, so to keep with safety, you can try this inside `prepareForSegue` using multiple bindings:

```
if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell, indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
    // use indexPath
}
```

Comment: I thought the cell would be the sender. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

This may Solve your problem :

```
var indexPath : NSArray = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
```