# Why cannot invoke 'indexPathForCell' with an argument of list type '(UICollectionView)'?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, viewcontroller

I created a `UICollectionView` with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3lwTzPBoLw).
And then I want pass `indexPath` from this UICollectionView to my GameViewController like in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899278/prepareforsegue-collectionview-indexpath-using-swift).

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: LevelCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Level", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LevelCell
    cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: levels[indexPath.row + 1]!.levelImage)
    cell.lblCell.text = levels[indexPath.row + 1]!.levelLabel
    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "StartGame" {
        if let gameView = segue.destinationViewController as? GameViewController {
            if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell, indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
                gameView.level = indexPath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work - even when I use `LevelCell` instead of `UICollectionViewCell`. I get this error:

Cannot invoke 'indexPathForCell' with an argument list of type '(UICollectionViewCell)'

**How can I get the indexPath of the element I just touched in my UICollectionView so that I can bypass it from this function to GameViewController?**

Answer (score 0):

You're casting the `sender`to `UICollectionView`, but it's probably `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell, indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
    gameView.level = indexPath
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. I was using `UICollectionViewCell` or `LevelCell` which is a cell as well. But I still get this error and do not know why.

Comment: Error must be somewhere else.

Comment: I must be a type casting or optional/non-optional problem. Is `collectionView` an unwrapped optional instance variable?

Comment: I did not define collectionView anywhere - I just found it in all answers.

Comment: In `prepareForSegue` the variable `collectionView` needs to be declared somewhere, it must be the reference to the `UICollectionView` instance